# Backslash in Ruby conditional statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was browsing some code and spotted this:

```
stem = ""

answer = ""

return if stem.nil? || answer.nil? || \
          stem.question == answer.question
```

What is the `\` for? I know `\` is used in strings, but I've never seen a use-case for this before. Is this a syntax error or some advanced ruby syntax? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a useless line-continuation character.

The question "is it a syntax error" seems pretty simple to discover.

Comment: It's useless in the above code, but not in general.

Comment: I don't have access to the codebase to run and I wondered if there was a unique purpose in mind by the author.

Comment: @jason328 You don't need access to the codebase, you just need Ruby, e.g., https://ideone.com/hC30WZ

Comment: Don't have access to ruby. Did not know about that site. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`\` is used to indicate line continuation in ruby. Using `\` will strip the `\n` (newline) character.

**Example (Using string):**

Without `\`:

```
2.1.2-perf :018 > s = "test this
2.1.2-perf :019"> out"
 => "test this\nout"
```

With `\`:

```
2.1.2-perf :020 > s = "test this \
2.1.2-perf :021"> out"
 => "test this out"
```

**Example (without using string):**

Without `\`:

```
2.1.2-perf :043 > return "test" if true && false &&
2.1.2-perf :044 >   true
 => nil
```

With `\`:

```
2.1.2-perf :045 > return "test" if true && false && \
2.1.2-perf :046 >   true
 => nil
```

In your case, it wouldn't matter, but it is not a syntax error.

From the [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html):

> Ruby programs are sequence of expressions. Each expression are delimited by semicolons(;) or newlines. Backslashes at the end of line does not terminate expression.

Comment: From your example it looks like ``\`` is related to strings.

Comment: @Stefan yes, I am showing the difference of using backslash and not using it because it doesn't matter in OP's example.

Comment: Your example is perfectly valid, but since the OP says *"I know ``\`` is used in strings"*, an example *without* a string might be more helpful.

Comment: @Stefan point taken, edited my answer. Thanks for the suggestion.